# Hierarchical GridView in ASP.NET with AJAX, JQuery implementation with child detail refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, c#-3.0

I found this article [here](http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2012/06/hierarchical-gridview-in-aspnet-with_27.html) with a pretty good base for what I need to do with master detail with an update in the detail grid using ajax.

The only problem I am having is that the child grid is not updating after a successful save of the record, I have tried several things but no good results.

The complete code in the posted article.

the main thing I do not understand is that when i step through it looks like it should be running the child page again, but it does not, also if you collapse and expand again it does not reload the child the grid, I really need it to load the child grid on every expand action.

I did upgrade to the current jquery with no issues, and the issue exists with both the jquery in the article and the current one.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of AJAX caching. Once the details are saved, the code is calling the server for getting new content using **ExpandCollapse**. but because the details already been retrieved from server using AJAX call, this returns the same content (without calling the server).

To solve the issue, you can add the url with date time appended as below -

```
$.ajax({
url: 'ChildGridBuilder.aspx?datetime=' + new Date().getTime(),
type: 'GET',
data: "OrderID=" + encodeURIComponent(orderId),
dataType: "html",
success: function (response) {
    $('#div' + orderId).html(response);
    $('#div' + orderId).css("display", "block");
    $('#img' + orderId).attr('src', 'images/minus.png');
    $('#hid' + orderId).val("1");
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert('Error Occured!');
    $('#div' + orderId).css("display", "none");
}
```

});

I had changed the page in the blog also, you can try to change the url and try again.